# EF - generic "AddOrUpdate" method suddenly breaks

Tags: entity-framework-4, webforms, asp.net-4.0

I am using Entity Framework 4 (database-first approach) in my ASP.NET 4.0 Webforms app.

What I'm basically doing is fetching the entity to be edited from my `ObjectContext`, and displaying the fields the user should enter data into (or modify existing data) on a web form.

When time comes to store the data back, I'm reading out the values from the web form, building up a new `Entity` instance, and then I have a generic method called `AddOrUpdate` that detects whether this is a new entity (so it needs to insert it), or if it's an existing one (so it needs to update the existing data).

My method using the `EntityKey` and checks to see if the object context already knows about this object - very similar to [what Cesar de la Torre of Microsoft shows here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cesardelatorre/archive/2008/09/04/updating-data-using-entity-framework-in-n-tier-and-n-layer-applications-short-lived-ef-contexts.aspx) in his blog post:

```
public static void AddOrUpdate(ObjectContext context, EntityObject objectDetached)
{
    if (objectDetached.EntityState == EntityState.Detached)
    {
        object currentEntityInDb = null;

        if (context.TryGetObjectByKey(objectDetached.EntityKey, out currentEntityInDb))
        {
            // attach and update the existing entity
        }
        else
        {
            // insert new entity into entity set
            context.AddObject(objectDetached.EntityKey.EntitySetName, objectDetached);
        } 
    }
}
```

This worked just fine - for the longest time. But today, suddenly, out of the blue, I keep getting exceptions like this on the `context.TryGetObjectByKey` statement:

> *System.InvalidOperationException: Object mapping could not be found for Type with identity 'MyEntityType'*

I cannot remember having changed anything in this core code at all - and the entity type is defined, the `ID` value that's stored in the `EntityKey` does indeed exist in the database... everything *should* be fine - but it keeps failing on me...

What on earth happened here??

I did find a few blog and forum posts on the topic, but none could really enlighten me or help me fix the issue. I must have messed up something - bad - but I really cannot see the forest for the trees - any hints?

Comment: Could the database structure been changed by someone? Any field inserted/removed or changed its type?

Comment: @anderson.pimentel: some additional columns were added to one of the tables - but I did update the EDMX model after that, and it did pick up on the new columns no problem.

Comment: @marc_s were some columns changed (besides the added ones)? Sometimes I experience some changed columns not getting recognized by the EDMX designer. The solution is then to remove and re-add the whole table in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally this sort of issue happens when EF cant find the assembly that has the type. With out seeing the full exception is difficult to figure out exactly but it seems your recent changes and the way you are using EF seems to be the cause.

EF ususally picks the type directly from the type itself when it has to access it using ObjectSet on the context. In the other cases where the type is not available from the context of the call it looks at the calling assembly and any dll's referenced by the calling assembly. Id it cant find it it throws the error message.

You can use the [LoadFromAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb495513(v=vs.110).aspx) method in the [MetadataWorkspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.metadataworkspace(v=vs.110).aspx) of the context.

> ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace.LoadFromAssembly(assembly).

This way EF will know where to look for your types.